# How to show that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}[X^n]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, expected-value

Let $X~ N(0, 1)$ be a normally distributed random variable.

I have to say I'm quite puzzled on how to actually show that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}[X^n]$. I was first wondering that a simple application of the monotone convergence theorem would do the trick, namely that $f = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(tX)^n}{n!}$, $f_n = \sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(tX)^m}{m!}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n = f$. But the MCT requires that the partial functions are non-negative, and while the $\exp$ is a non-negative function, the partial sums might not be. How could the equality be proven rigorously?

Comment: The sum for $e^x$ converges absolutely uniformly everywhere.

Comment: When monotone convergence fails, try dominated convergence...

Comment: Let $\sharp$ denote the counting measure on $\mathbb Z_+$. Write
$$\mathbb E[\exp(tX)]=\mathbb E\!\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^nX^n}{n!}\right]$$ as
$$\iint\,\frac{t^n\,x^n}{n!}\,\sharp(\mathrm dn)\,\mathbb P(X\in\mathrm dx)$$
and use Fubini's theorems.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yeah I just realized it. If I've shown that $\mathbb{E}[\exp(|tX|)] < +\infty$, then I'm basically done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$
\operatorname{E}[e^{tX}]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tx}f_X(x)\,d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{(tx)^n}{n!}f_X(x)\,d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{t^n}{n!}x^n f_X(x)\,d x\tag1
$$

so you only need to justify the exchange of the sum and the integral in the last expression. For this you can notice that

$$
\operatorname{E}[e^{t|X|}]=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{t|x|}e^{-x^2/2}\,d t=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}2+tx}\,d x
=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x+t)^2+t^2}2}\,d x<\infty\tag2 
$$

for any chosen $t\in \mathbb{R}$, therefore you can apply Fubini's theorem in (1) to exchange the sum and the integral sign.∎